# Can we get the dosage list for a drug

Tags: openfda

How can we get the dosage list for a particular drug. we have the key "dosage_forms_and_strength" but it gives a single string not in a list format.
I need to bind a dropdown for dosage information for a drug

Comment: Where did you get this data from? Can you show an example of what exactly you're looking for and what authority might have it?

Answer (score 0):

When using the openFDA Drug Label API, you can obtain the drug's NDC product code. For example, using Amoxicillin from your other question, NDC code would be 50090-0714:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.generic_name:Amoxicillin

```
"openfda": {
    "product_ndc": [
      "50090-0714"
    ],
```

Then you can query the openFDA NDC API using the product code obtained above, such as: https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:50090-0714. The API will provide you with *structured* information about the product's packaging, which you can use to build your dropdown:

```
"packaging": [
    {
      "marketing_start_date": "20141128",
      "package_ndc": "50090-0714-0",
      "description": "20 TABLET, FILM COATED in 1 BOTTLE (50090-0714-0)",
      "sample": false
    }
  ]
```

Hope this helps.